# Erro em alteração dee tabela no PostgreSQL. Como faço para alterar o tipo de uma colulna int para o tipo timestamp?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, tabela-html

Estou estudando o BD PostgreSQL por um recente livro que adquiri. Ao tentar alterar uma tebela com base no comando que aprendi no livro ocorreu um erro, usei exatamente o mesmo comando escrito no livro sem alteração. Estou tentado alterar um campo tipo int para tipo timestamp mas o seguinte erro ocorre

--alteração em tabela com alteração de coluna tipo int para tipo timestamp

alter table comissoes 
alter column data_pagamento type timestamp 
using data_pagamento_timestamp;

obs: no livro está escrito data_pagamento_timestamp. Timestamp é um tipo no SQL para armazenar data e hora porém com "*timestamp" fica como parte do nome da tabela. Retirei o "*" e deixei timestamp separado do nome da coluna por considerar que isso era um erro do livro mas não adiantou pois continua sem funcionar. Como corrigir isso?

o erro que ocorre abaixo:

LINE 1: ...ata_pagamento type timestamp using data_pagamento timestamp;
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 87

Answer (score 0):

timestamp es una fecha con una hora.

Para transformar números en timestamp hay que indicar esos números qué representan (segundos, minutos, horas). Y a qué corresponde el 0.

Por ejemplo si son segundos y hoy es el momento 0:

```
create table table11(
  id serial primary key,
  seconds int
);

insert into table11 (seconds) values 
  (15), (60), (60*60);

alter table table11 alter seconds type timestamp
  using '2018-11-18'::date + (seconds||' seconds')::interval;

select * from table11;
```

Observe que a parte `USING` é aquela que indica como a transformação deve ser feita.

Para ver um exemplo, acesse: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9f687c66e2fa82bddd14130d82c27b3a